# How can I use scrollIntoView() with mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, laravel-6

I have a Vue component and the template has some div elements, a few images and a User object passed over from Laravel 6.0 Everything seems to work just fine until I try to use scrollIntoView() with the mounted() function. From what I can tell the page is trying to scrollIntoView() before it is completely loaded. If I limit the user object to a small size (just 2 users) everything works fine. But if there is more data it does not scroll to view like it should. It does work if I use a set timeout function but it looks hackey and not professional.

I just want to scroll to a div (the header) after view is mounted/loaded. The div is the first div on the page and has no images (if that even matters). Can anyone help me to solve this? I have seen that the mounted function only applies to the virtual DOM? If so what can we use in Vue that is more like JQuery $(document).ready() but for the specific component and applies to the actual DOM?

```
  mounted() {       
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("move-to-header");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: When mounted is being called the component should be loaded and rendered. Is there any kind of asynchronous code loading the data?

Comment: Do you create new components based on number of User objects? If so, you might create identical instances of mounted function. Solution is, to extract-paste code into  the parent component. (You basicaly want to scroll once, not many times as the number of Users). If the answer is not sufficient, can you please provide more code?

Comment: OK, so thanks for the idea that it might be the asynchronous code loading that is messing things up. I move my code from mounted to the callback function of my axios (asynchronous code) request and it seems to be working. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the callback function of my axios request. I did however need to wrap it in a setTimeout function with no specified number of milliseconds but overall it is working without errors.

```
  get_user(the_name) {
      axios
        .post("/get_users", { the_name: the_name})
        .then(response => {
           this.display_user(response.data);
           setTimeout(() => {
             var elmnt = document.getElementById("move-to-header");
             elmnt.scrollIntoView();
   })
```